# Darkened overlay on hover is LARGER than image

Tags: html, css, image, hover, overlay

Trying to achieve a darkened overlay (with text) on hovering over an image. It works but I get some additional space above the image that's darkened as well (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7hpM.png).

**Any help on what I'm doing wrong?**

I'm a beginner trying to apply this to a WordPress site (theme: Snaps). Hence, a workaround within the browser version of WordPress' CSS editor  would be very much appreciated!

```css
/* Main container */

.overlay-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Original image */

.overlay-image .image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Original text overlay */

.overlay-image .text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}


/* Overlay on hover */


/* New overlay on hover */

.overlay-image .hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}


/* New overlay appearance on hover */

.overlay-image:hover .hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Background and text only overlay on hover */

.overlay-image .normal {
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlay-image:hover .normal {
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay-image .hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-image">
  <a href="LINK_URL">
    <img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/tyPnKUE.png" alt="Alt text" />
    <div class="normal">
      <div class="text">Image + text ORIGINAL
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="text">Background + text HOVER
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

HTML and CSS sourced from: https://pavenum.com/en/images-and-text-overlays-in-html-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
font-size: 0;
```

to the parent element

Comment: I edited his question into a snippet. Just waiting peer review.

Comment: still works fine.. what i mean is his code doesn't replicate the issue in his question..

Comment: This is the actual code that causes the issue from my screenshot (minus the picture I use of course)... Could this mean that the theme I'm using causes the additional space?

Comment: have you ensured the image doesn't have any white space? if you run code snippet, you can see that there's no white space on the above when you hover, so maybe the problem is in the image

Comment: @Christian Share a link of your image somewhere, so we can use it in the snippet.

Comment: There you go: https://imgur.com/tyPnKUE
@ErwinSanders: No, there's no white space in the image (sadly).

Comment: Update your image to your snippet, it works fine with no white space on top.. i'm guessing you didn't copy the styles correctly

Comment: @ErwinSanders: Double checked and styles are copied correctly. But: Your new answer solved the issue! Thank you very much!

Would you mind explaining why this solution worked (sorry, beginner here...) or what was wrong in the first place? The snippet obviously worked in the first place (astonishingly)...

Comment: @Christian The joy of a web developer right there for you!

Comment: @Christian you're welcome, i assume that multiple elements is the culprit here. this is one of the odd things of styling, sometimes there will be white space between elements if you're using display inline-block, i don't have the exact explanation as why this occurs either, but it's something that i always try when there's a white space in between my elements..